# Change the Font size of the legend in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a figure with a legend in Matlab, I want to know how to change the fontsize of the legend (ie: increase the size of the words "speed" and "distance")

```
plot(x1,y1,x2,y2)
legend('speed','distance')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had searched a bit, you would have found it:

From the documentation of [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html)

```
figure
plot(x,ydata,'*',x,ycos)
legend({'Collected Data','y = cos(x)'},'FontSize',8,'FontWeight','bold')
```

It's pretty clear I think.

Comment: What version are you using? This does not work in all versions. It warns that `Fontsize` is an extra legend entry and will get ignored, but it also has an error that it's an invalid argument. I'm using `9.2.0.556344 (R2017a)`.